# Family members in factor analysis

Tags: pca, sampling, factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm carrying out an exploratory PCA, followed by an CFA, to test for dimensionality of a questionnaire. I am wondering about the effect of having family members in the same sample.

I have a final sample of 1060 in total. This is made up of 530 autistic men (39 of whom are parents) and 530 autistic women (39 of whom are parents), with each sample matched approximately by age. It is fairly likely that the children of these parents also completed the questionnaire and would be included in the sample, although there is no way of knowing which respondents these are.

Should I remove the parents because the common home environment may lead to specific shared interests/lack of interests, thereby contributing to common variance in the factor analysis? I thought that this would be minimal as they would only be in clusters of twos or threes or fours, and it would be a shame to eliminate all 78 participants.

I'd really appreciate any help, thank you so much!

-Thea

Comment: Interesting.  But all you've said about the content is the indirect mention of "interests/lack of interests."  Please say more about what's been asked of your participants.  Also, to which population do you want to make inferences--that of non-parents alone?

Comment: The questionnaire is designed to measure 'systemising' - the drive to construct systems (e.g. mechanic/ linguistic / natural). I would say it's likely, therefore, that an autistic mother or father that is interested in systems such as cars/ planes/ stock markets/ weather patterns/ etc would influence their autistic child to be interested in the same things.

Comment: And I am looking to draw conclusions about Autistic men and women generally. Specifically, I want to see whether their answers cluster along two or three factors of "systemising", or whether systemising ability can be considered unidimensional.

Comment: It seems there is no way to make the desired inferences about all autistic *men and women* without either excluding the parents among them or including the children.  Maybe you'll want to try it both ways to see how or to what extent results differ.  But I hope you will conduct the CFA on a different sub-sample than used for the EFA.  Otherwise it's circular; or you might say like shooting fish in a barrel.

Comment: Hello, yes I am splitting the samples and carrying out EFA and CFA separately! Actually on that point I actually have a second question... I was going to randomly mix the total samples and then split it... but am I better off also matching these groups by sex/age?

Comment: And thank you for your answer! I will try carrying it out both ways. Could I maybe get a bit of clarification on why I should either excluding the parents among them or including the children, with reference to the variance etc? Thanks so much, this is for my udnergrad dis and i really appreciate it